# Instructions for STRLEN function in AVX with YMM registers

Tags: assembly, avx, avx2

i am creating **strlen** function with **AVX** (not AVX2) ...
with AVX it's possible to access to the (YMM) registers but there is a problem ... the instructions that i know for strlen functions are :

```
vmovdqu
vpcmpeqb
vpmovmskb
```

but these instructions only works for 'XMM' in AVX ... and if i want to use them with (YMM), i need to have a AVX2-CPU ... but im talking about AVX ...
now for creating a strlen function with 'AVX' and 'YMM' registers, what instructions I have to use ?

Comment: Also try `pcmpistrm` and `pcmpistri` perhaps.

Comment: this is still SSE (4.2) and AVX (XMM) not AVX (YMM)

Comment: I know.  But these instructions were specifically made for this purpose.  AVX instructions have no performance difference to SSE instructions if both use 128 bit registers and since using 256 bit registers is out of question, this is a possible choice.

Comment: but the speed of 'pcmpistri' is really bad !!!!!!!!!! it's even 30 % slower than SSE2 !

Comment: Depends on the use case, but for this case probably yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to do byte compares with YMM registers without AVX2.  There are literally no byte-element YMM instructions in AVX1.

AVX1 is only useful for 256-bit *floating point* vectors, or copying / shuffling arbitrary data.  Most integer / bit-exact things aren't possible until AVX2; that's why AVX2 exists.

**Use XMM registers** like you would for an SSE2 strlen, with the only benefit from AVX1 being saving on `movdqa` register-copy instructions.

You could hypothetically unpack bytes to floats (slowly, with shuffles + vinsertf128), and then compare 8 at once with `vcmpps`.  But you can compare 16 bytes at once with `vpcmpeqb xmm` so do that like a normal person and get twice as much work done per vector, while still getting the benefit of AVX non-destructive 3-operand instruction encoding.

Comment: So AVX for strlen function is just SSE2 with solving 'rewrite on xmm after vpcmpeqb' problem ... true ?

Comment: @ELHASKSERVERS: Yes, that's exactly what my answer says.  BTW, you might want to look at glibc's strlen which uses `vpminub`.  See [Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?](//stackoverflow.com/q/37800739) and [Why is this code 6.5x slower with optimizations enabled?](//stackoverflow.com/a/55589634) for links and summary of glibc's strlen, and more info on vectorizing strlen.